# How to add custom network throttling in playwright-lighthouse package

Tags: reactjs, playwright, lighthouse, lighthouse-ci

I want to add network throttling 3g config in the [**[playwright-lighthouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/playwright-lighthouse)**] package, I don't know where exactly to pass the config, even though I am running a CDP session I don't see a difference in lighthouse metrics report when run on slow 3g, the results are same as in default network condition, as the lighthouse itself uses some simulation throttling so do not know how to override that, as the requirement is to run the test case in different network conditions and see if there are differences in performances metrics of lighthouse report when run on different network conditions.

```
test('lighthouse playwright metrics uisng slow 3g network condition', async ({ playwright }) => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9223'],
  });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const pageNum = await context.newPage();
  const cdpSession = await context.newCDPSession(pageNum);

  await cdpSession.send('Network.emulateNetworkConditions',{
  offline:false,
  downloadThroughput: ((500 * 1000) / 8) * 0.8,
  uploadThroughput: ((500 * 1000) / 8) * 0.8,
  latency: 400 * 5,
});

  await pageNum.goto(HOME_PAGE_URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
  const report = await playAudit({
    page: pageNum,
    thresholds: {
      performance: 50,
    },
    reports: {
      formats: { html: true },
      name: 'playwright-lighthouse-report slow 3g',
      directory: './e2e/playwright-lighthouse-report-' + Date.now().toString(),
    },
    port: 9223,
  });

  expect(report.lhr.audits['cumulative-layout-shift'].numericValue).toBeLessThan(CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT);
  expect(report.lhr.audits['first-contentful-paint'].numericValue).toBeLessThan(FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_THRESHOLD);
  expect(report.lhr.audits['speed-index'].numericValue).toBeLessThan(SPEED_INDEX_THRESHOLD);
  expect(report.lhr.audits['largest-contentful-paint'].numericValue).toBeLessThan(LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_THRESHOLD);
  expect(report.lhr.audits['interactive'].numericValue).toBeLessThan(TIME_TO_INTERACTIVE_THRESHOLD);
  expect(report.lhr.audits['max-potential-fid'].numericValue).toBeLessThan(FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_THRESHOLD);
});
```